# Radiance Theme : Wrong colour Title Bars - Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome fallback compiz

Tags: 16.04, gnome-session-fallback, radiance

My **Radiance** theme display colours appears to be somewhat confused.

My display shows:

- **SILVER** Title Bar in some apps / components

  - the expected colours for **Radiance**
- **SLATE** Title Bar in some apps / components

  - the expected colours for **Ambience**

I have this configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Gnome Classic

  - *gnome-flashback session (with compiz)*
- Theme

  - *Radiance*

These **components** show the correct **Pale-Grey** or **Silver** colours:

- Gnome Panels
- Gnome Menu

This **apps** show the correct **Pale-Grey** or **Silver** Title Bar:

- Nautilus

But the majority of my other apps have the **Slate** Title Bar

- although the DropDown menus are displaying correctly

Here is an example of what I **want**:

[image]

Here is an example of what I **get currently**:

[image]

With Ubuntu 14.04 I was using the same gnome fallback configuration and everything displayed correctly for Radiance.

With my new install of 16.04 I have the current problem.

---

Is it possible that I have incomplete theme files for Gnome / GTK ?

Should I be looking for a complete Radiance theme somewhere and installing that ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open dconf Editor from Menu/System tools, go to org/gnome/metacity/theme and type Radiance instead Ambiance

credits to this dude
https://askubuntu.com/a/820346/590091

Comment: Thank you! No idea why a metacity setting affects my gnome-flashback compiz ... but the end result is slick & pretty again.