# Window border in Radiance theme having color of Ambiance theme

Tags: radiance

DE is gnome fallback, ubuntu 16.10. Changing theme from default Ambiance to Radiance or Adwaita not apply for color of window border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about gnome-session-flashback, and if you are changing via Unity Tweak Tool, it does not change meracity theme for Window Decorations, you need to change it manually  in dconf-editor or by:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity theme Radiance
```

Ofc., Radiance can be replaced with any theme name.

Comment: Wow worked! Not via command but going to dconf org/gnome/metacity/theme and typing Radiance instead Ambiance fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, I don't know why it would not work with command, it should.